# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields won't work properly

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add new fields to the Contact Field group but once i try to add more new fields, they just won't show.

Is it because of the website theme, maybe it's blocking how many fields there can be in the Contact fields?
[image: Website place where i want to add more fields]

[image: Picture of things i want to add]

As you can see in the 2nd picture, there are things like: Vadovė and Telefonas 3 and Telefonas 3 paaiškinimas that won't show.

This the Custom Fields group:[image]

Comment: Without seeing the code, we really don't know. You need to actually call the fields in the PHP to display them. Unless the theme supports that, those fields will not display.

Comment: How should i do that? With crome in inspect element or by going to the website files and seing the code?

Comment: You can't view PHP in dev tools. You need to look at the actual PHP files.

Comment: I have no access to enter to the website files

Comment: @disinfor Btw what file or what should i search in the website files? The website theme php code or what?

Comment: I have no idea where you should look. Every theme is different. You could search for `main_phone_1` in the code and you'll find it. Also, you should **never** edit the theme's files directly. You'll need to create a child theme first.